# Every vector is a linear combination of $n$ linearly independent vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

In $\mathbb R^n$, let $\mathbf{v}_{1}$, $\mathbf{v}_{2}$, $\dots$, and $\mathbf{v}_{n}$ be linearly independent vectors (i.e. if $\alpha_{1}\mathbf{v}_{1}+\alpha_{2}\mathbf{v}_{2}+\dots+\alpha_{n}\mathbf{v}_{n}=\mathbf{0}$ and $\mathbf{v}_{1}$, $\mathbf{v}_{2}$, $\dots$, and $\mathbf{v}_{n}$ are distinct, then $\alpha_{1},\alpha_{2},\dots,\alpha_{n}=0$). Let $\mathbf{u}$ be a vector.

Show that $\mathbf{u}$ is a linear combination of $\mathbf{v}_{1}$, $\mathbf{v}_{2}$, $\dots$, and $\mathbf{v}_{n}$ (i.e. $\mathbf{u}=\beta_{1}\mathbf{v}_{1}+\beta_{2}\mathbf{v}_{2}+\dots+\beta_{n}\mathbf{v}_{n}$ for some $\beta_{1}, \beta_{2},\dots,\beta_{n}\in \mathbb R$).

(We have already proven that if $\mathbf{v}_{1}$, $\mathbf{v}_{2}$, $\dots$, and $\mathbf{v}_{n}$ are linearly independent, then each vector cannot be written as a linear combination of the other vectors.)

---

Context: High school

Goal (not sure if this is possible): Prove using only rules of arithmetic with real numbers and vectors (e.g. $(1,2)+(3,4)=(4,6)$, $3(1,2)=(3,6)$, $-(1,2)=(-1,-2)$) and **without** introducing such additional concepts as span, basis, dimension, vector space, matrix, row reduction, inverse of matrix, etc.

Comment: So you are telling me $v_1=e_1,v_2=e_1$ are linearly independent?

Comment: @user10354138: I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: The standard proofs, usually involving some replacement lemma, are about as bare-boned as proofs get. They will use the idea of spanning, and often basis, but these are terms that could be danced around if need be; they only exist to make communication more concise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an induction proof on $n$.

If $v_1$ is linearly independent on $\Bbb{R}$, then $v_1 \neq 0$ (otherwise $1v_1 = 0$, where $1 \neq 0$). We can then write any $x \in \Bbb{R}$ as:
$$x = \frac{x}{v_1} v_1.$$
This establishes the base case.

Now, suppose that, for any $x \in \Bbb{R}^n$ and any linearly independent $w_1, \ldots, w_n \in \Bbb{R}^n$, there exist $b_1, \ldots, b_n$ such that $x = b_1w_1 + \ldots + b_n w_n$.

Consider a linearly independent list of vectors $v_1, \ldots, v_{n+1} \in \Bbb{R}^{n+1}$. Note, if it is the case that every one of the standard basis vectors $e_1, \ldots, e_{n+1}$ can be formed as a linear combination of $v_1, \ldots, v_{n+1}$, then we are done, since linear combinations of linear combinations are linear combinations.

Otherwise, let us suppose $e_i$ cannot be formed as a linear combination of $v_1, \ldots, v_{n+1}$. Let:
$$w_k = v_k - (v_k \cdot e_i) e_i,$$
where $\cdot$ is the dot product, and hene $w_k$ is simply $v_k$ with its $i$th entry set to $0$. I claim that $w_1, \ldots, w_{n+1}$ are linearly independent.

Suppose $a_1, \ldots, a_{n+1}$ are such that
$$0 = \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} a_k(v_k - (v_k \cdot e_i)e_i) = \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} a_kv_k - \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}v_k \cdot e_i\right)e_i.$$
Note that, if $\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}v_k \cdot e_i = 0$, then $\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} a_kv_k = 0$, so by linear independence of $v_1, \ldots, v_{n+1}$, we have $a_1 = \ldots = a_{n+1} = 0$, and we are done. Otherwise, we get
$$e_i = \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} a_k \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} v_k \cdot e_i\right)^{-1} v_k,$$
which contradicts our assumption about $e_i$. So, the vectors $w_1, \ldots w_{n+1}$ are linearly independent.

But, since all the vectors $w_1, \ldots, w_{n+1}$ have $0$ in their $i$th coordinate, we can simply embed them in $\Bbb{R}^n$, by removing this coordinate. This gives us $n+1$ linearly independent vectors in $\Bbb{R}^n$.

If we just look at the first $n$ of these vectors, which are automatically linearly independent, then the $n+1$th vector is a linear combination of the first the $n$, by the induction hypothesis. This leads to a linear combination of the $n+1$ vectors in $\Bbb{R}^n$, which is a contradiction. Thus, no such standard basis vector $e_i$ exists, and all vectors can be expressed as a linear combination of $v_1, \ldots, v_{n+1}$.

Comment: I realized this is called the [Steinitz exchange lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinitz_exchange_lemma).

Comment: @user103496 I've never heard it called so (I'm used to seeing at as just the exchange lemma, or exchange principle), but yes, this is essentially an adaptation of this idea. By performing a single exchange with the standard basis, we can knock out a coordinate, and rely on the rest by induction.